# How to convert XML files to Excel file in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a bunch of **XML** files in `Marklogic` DB.

I want to convert all the xml files to Excel files and store in local.

Is there any way to convert?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing I could point you to right now is the [MarkLogic Toolkit for Excel](http://developer.marklogic.com/code/marklogic-toolkit-for-excel). That version is a bit dated, but it's the best that's publicly available.

For the curious, yes, we plan to migrate it from codeplex (it's home as of April 2017) to GitHub.